# Column data moving to right with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Below is my excl data:

```
A    B       c  ... F               G

1   test    vb1     testing1        open
2   test1   vb2     testing1        close
2   test2   vb3     testing1 
4   test3   vb4     testing1
```

I want to move F column data  to B column and shift B column data to right; so before B will be C.

How can I do with this using Excel VBA programming?

Comment: Have you tried to record a macro while doing it manually and have a look at the code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveColumns()

With ActiveSheet
    .Columns("F:F").Cut
    .Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    .Columns("C:C").Cut
    .Columns("E:E").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

To use this:

- open the Visual Basic Editor: Tools > Macro > Visual Basic Editor
- insert a module (right-click on VBAProject and Insert > Module)
- paste the above code in this new module.

You can then execute the code from Excel: Tools > Macro... > Macros...

[EDIT] Another try without copy-pasting

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyWithArray()
Dim lLastrow As Long
Dim aValues As Variant

With ActiveSheet
    lLastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AE").Row
    'store data from the column F
    aValues = .Range("F1:F" & lLastrow).Value
    '"move" data a column further
    .Range("C1:AE" & lLastrow).Value = .Range("B1:AD" & lLastrow).Value
    'copy data from column C to column B
    .Range("B1:B" & lLastrow).Value = .Range("C1:C" & lLastrow).Value
    'restore data copied from column F to column B
    .Range("B1:B" & lLastrow).Value = aValues
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I have columns upto AE.Is it possible to without cut and insert on every column

Comment: @user569125: I've edited my answer with another try but I really think this won't work faster than the first one

Comment: What do you mean by "Is it possible to without cut and insert on every column"?.  Jmax's first method does not cut and insert every column.  It cuts and pastes one column and moves all the others to the right.  Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

> > > so Before B will be C.

I had to re read it many times to actually understand what you are trying to say. And I might not have still got it correct. :) Are you saying this? Please confirm.

"So B will now be in place of C as C moves 1 place towards right when you insert F in place of B"

If yes, then all you need is just the first two lines from Jmax's code

```
Sub Sample()
    Columns("F:F").Cut
    Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End Sub
```