# Order columns with similar data into same row using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying merge rows that contain similar data using the easiest method possible, but i assume it will require some VBA. If anybody is able to point me in the right direction that would be great.

An example of what i'm trying to achieve is:

```
NAME | AGE|   AREA    
John | 32 | Devon
Will | 32 | Devon
Matt | 28 | Pool
Dave | 32 | Devon
Phil | 28 | Pool
Tony | 25 | Blackpool
```

Turned into:

```
AGE|   AREA      | Name 1 | Name 2 | Name 3 |
32 | Devon  | John   | Dave   | Will   | 
28 | Pool | Matt   | Phil   |        |
25 | Blackpool  | Tony   |        |        |
```

EDIT: I've managed to pile together what i need, however it seems to place the non duplicate data into the same column as opposed to my preferred `Name 1 | Name 2 | Name 3` any thoughts on updating this to populate separate cells rather than the same?

Here is the update:

```
Sub mergeCategoryValues()
    Dim lngRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim columnToMatch As Integer: columnToMatch = 2
        Dim columnToConcatenate As Integer: columnToConcatenate = 1

        lngRow = .Cells(65536, columnToMatch).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(columnToMatch).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Cells(columnToMatch), Header:=xlYes

        Do
            If .Cells(lngRow, columnToMatch) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToMatch) Then
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate) & "; " & .Cells(lngRow, columnToConcatenate)
            .Rows(lngRow).Delete
            End If

            lngRow = lngRow - 1
        Loop Until lngRow = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Nobody will write the code for you so it's unclear to me what you are asking by saying *`point me in the right direction`*. What is considered the *`right direction`* in this case? You can hire a freelancer if you don't know any VBA but if you do know some, show your attempt at solving the problem and then tell us what did not work and where you are stuck exactly. As it stands your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. See [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for info.

Comment: My apologies for your confusion, but by right direction i did not mean somebody to complete the job for me. Merely point me at some places to research or some functions to look into so i can write my own code. Although i do not profess to know VBA i can find my way around most solutions eventually.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it

Comment: Thank you for informing me, after some digging and piling together i've updated the question to seem a little more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
If .Cells(lngRow, columnToMatch) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToMatch) Then
```

Do you expect to get into the condition?
If lngRow is set previously (in your case to 7) and columnToMatch is 1, unless the cells(7,1) and (6,1) have the same info it won't do anything.

Comment: Sorry, i pulled some of the code from the web and forgot to update it to suit my question. I've now changed the value of `columnToMatch` to the correct column.

Comment: How would you go about removing the `"; "` separator and instead placing the combined data into separate columns?

Comment: @Giles you can do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194277/column-data-moving-to-right-with-excel-vba