# Change order of column contents in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I am interested in changing the order of the contents of a table column in Excel by a certain rule, re-ordering my whole table this way.
I will post an example here so that you will understand.

Let's say that you have this column in the table:

```
Column
 A
 B
 C
 B
 C
 A
 A
 B
 C
```

I want it to look in the end like this:

```
 Column
   A
   B
   C
   A
   B
   C
   A
   B
   C
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194277/column-data-moving-to-right-with-excel-vba You can simply move the columns around using the function in the first answer. It may not be exactly what you're looking for, because in your example the letters repeat, and I'm not sure if that means you want duplicates?

Comment: I wasn't referring to this... A B C A ,etc. are not the column headers, are the column contents.

Answer (score 0):

Try with blow code.

**Note :** I worked with Sheet8

```
Sub orderchange()
    Dim lastcolumn, i, keyval As Long
    Dim fixit As String
    lastcolumn = Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To lastcolumn Step 3
        If Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i) = "A" And Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 1) = "B" And Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 2) = "C" Then
            'nothing
        Else
            If Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i) <> "A" And Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 1) = "A" Then
                fixit = Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i)
                Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i) = Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 1)
                Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 1) = fixit
            ElseIf Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i) <> "A" And Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 2) = "A" Then
                fixit = Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i)
                Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i) = Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 2)
                Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 2) = fixit
            End If

            If Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 1) <> "B" And Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 2) = "B" Then
                fixit = Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 1)
                Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 1) = Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 2)
                Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 2) = fixit
            ElseIf Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 1) <> "B" And Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i) = "B" Then
                fixit = Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 1)
                Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 1) = Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i)
                Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i) = fixit
            End If

            If Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 2) <> "C" And Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i) = "C" Then
                fixit = Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 2)
                Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 2) = Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i)
                Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i) = fixit
            ElseIf Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 2) <> "C" And Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 1) = "C" Then
                fixit = Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 2)
                Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 2) = Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 1)
                Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, i + 1) = fixit
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Proof of Work**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! But A,B,C... are the contents of the  column. So there is a single column, with the rows containing A,B,C.... Think you can modify the code so it can do this?

Comment: I can't get you what you are saying. Yes A, B, C are the contents of the column. Don't you need that? if yes what you expected. Pls say clearly with snaps